# Change ptTimeSelect behavior while using validationEngine plugin

Tags: jquery, timepicker, jquery-validation-engine

I have a input field which is set to display ptTimeSelect time picker. For the same field, I need to use validationEngine to execute field required validation.

Now here's the issue:

1. Initially, input field is blank.
2. Click inside the text area, it will display the time picker.
3. Set some time.
4. It starts showing inline validation error and the field context is lost. So to remove the error, I have to go inside the text area and tab out.

I want the behavior so that whenever a field value is set from time picker, field required validation error should be gone.

I tried setting the onchange event at input, but that is not working.

I can make it work by modifying the ptTimeSelect js query. But I don't want to do that.

Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$('#Time').ptTimeSelect({
     onClose: function(){
                jQuery('#myForm').validationEngine('validateField', '#Time');
          }
 });
```

"Time" being the Id of the field on which you applied the timepicker.